# Tinymce randomly not rendered in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor, tinymce

I'm come here because i have a big issue with Meteorjs + Tinymce. Hope you can help me...

Let me explain my situation.

I have a base template for a multi-step form that i made myself.
In this base template, there is a dynamic template function, that rendered each step (on click on next button, it render the next step.)

There are my differents template :

AdminTrainingsInsertForm (base)

1. trainer (1rst step)
2. training (2nd step)
3. essential (3rd step)
4. practical (4th step) <- it's in this step that i render tinymce on 3 textarea
5. schedule (5th step)

this is my code for render the tinymce, when my practical step (template) is rendered :

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".tinyted",
    plugins: [
        'autolink link'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | link bullist',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    inline: false,
    skin_url: '/packages/teamon_tinymce/skins/lightgray',
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.on('keydown', function(e) {
            var body = tinymce.get($(this)[0].id).getBody(), text = tinymce.trim(body.innerText || body.textContent);

            var ref = $('textarea[id='+$(this)[0].id+']');
            text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
            var len = text.length;
            var maxChar = parseInt(ref.data('max'));

            if ( (len) > maxChar ) { // prevent type because text length > max chars authorized
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            }

            // update count words div
            if ($(this)[0].id == 'practical-description')
                $('#description-count').html(len);
            if ($(this)[0].id == 'practical-details')
                $('#details-count').html(len);
            if ($(this)[0].id == 'practical-agenda')
                $('#agenda-count').html(len);

        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, the tinymce is init on textarea with the class **tinyted**

The problem is : 
I'm doing one flow in my multi-step form, the tinymce is rendered. I validate it, insert all the datas in my mongodb and render the list of all those differents datas.
Next, i'm redoing a new flow with that multi-step, and in the step 4, the tinymce is not rendered... So it's a **show-stopper** issue :(

Someone as a solution or a way to fix this please ? Thanks for your futures answers !

Comment: So are you saying that when you first reach step 4 things work but if you leave and return to step 4 TinyMCE does not render?

Comment: That's right... any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a SPA style framework that loads/unloads TinyMCE you need to make sure you `init()` and `remove()` TinyMCE at the right time.

When you want to load TinyMCE you use `init()` which you appear to do correctly the first time.

When you "leave" that step you need to properly `remove()` each TinyMCE instance ***before the framework removes the relevant DOM elements***.

When you then return to the step you can once again use `init()`.  If you don't `remove()` TinyMCE when leaving the step it still has an editor object but its now pointing to DOM objects that no longer exist hence TinyMCE does not "work".

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i used it : tinymce.remove(".tinyted"); and it did the trick !